# Coolant leak in my 2013 Ford escape

Tags: ford, coolant-leak, escape

Coolant leak is coming from the torque mount thats connected to the transmission mount. I took the covering off the back to look down at the hoses, could not see a leak.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Could you help us out a little bit here? Which exact mount are you talking about? Could you take a picture of it an put it in your question? Are you sure it's coolant and not water? Is the coolant level going down?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: it is coolant, its dripping off the torque mount thats with the transmission mount. yes, when I fill the reservoir you see the level going down. when I start the motor it drips faster. I also looked behind the motor at the hose that is known to leak. that is like 3 junction hose. Its not that.